# Is there any way of removing header from SSR page serverApp-state before it is inserted in HTLM using Angular?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular11

I need to remove specific header (Date) from the Angular Universal SSR page, so that final HTML won't have this value in file. Considering that I cannot remove this header from API server response, is there any way to achieve this using Angular?

Here is the example of serverApp-state script tag, inserted on page, with that header:

```
<script id="serverApp-state" type="application/json">
...
&q;headers&q;:{&q;date&q;:[&q;Fri, 05 Mar 2021 12:44:26 GMT&q;],&q;content-type&q;:[&q;application/json; charset=utf-8&q;],&q;content-length&q;:[&q;2933&q;],&q;connection&q;:[&q;keep-alive&q;],&q;server&q;:[&q;nginx/1.18.0&q;],&q;vary&q;:[&q;origin,accept-encoding&q;],&q;cache-control&q;:[&q;no-cache&q;],&q;accept-ranges&q;:[&q;bytes&q;]}
...
</script>
```

Comment: What do you use to serialise the API responses?

Comment: @David might be wrong, as I'm a newbie to angular, but this is done by angular-universal under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the default `TransferHttpCacheModule`, this module will register an interceptor that will cache xhr responses, including headers, in the transfer state  (see [interceptor's code](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/common/src/transfer_http.ts))

So, if you do not want these headers, here are a few options

**Option #1**

you can write your own interceptor, based on the default one, but do not cache headers. Once this is done, you just need to provide your interceptor in your app module providers

```
providers:[
    //...,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MyOwnTokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }]
```

**Option #2**

Use `BEFORE_APP_SERIALIZED` token so that you can modify the DOM document before it it serialised.

**Option #3**

In your `server.ts` file, change the default routing so that you can modify the html string before sending it

```
  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, res, providers: [/*....*/] },
      (err: Error, html: string) => {
        
        if(!html)
        {
          res.status(500);
        }
        else
        {
            //Modify html here to remove the headers
        }
      res.send(html || err.message);
    });
```